# Finding the particular and general solutions to Einstein Field Equations under generalized Vaidya Geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, elliptic-pde, general-relativity, tensor

The problem I have is on finding the particular and general solutions to Einstein Field Equations under generalized Vaidya Geometry, which comes from the following paper : https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.90.064034

In particular I am trying to find the:

(a) Particular solution of the resulting equations, and

(b) The General solution of the resulting equations.

Currently I am trying to solve for $m$ , $\psi_{v}$ and $\psi_{r}$. in the following 2 equations.

\begin{equation}
 \frac{2\dot{m}(v,r)}{r^{2}}= \Psi^{2}_{v}+ \left(1-\frac{2m(v,r)}{r}\right)\Psi_{v}\Psi_{r}. 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{m^{\prime\prime}(v,r)}{r}= \Psi_{v}\Psi_{r} - \frac{2m^{'}(v,r)}{r^{2}} 
\end{equation}
Any help, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: presumably $\dot{m}$ and $m'$ denote two different derivatives of $m$? Which is which? Also, are $\psi_v$ and $\psi_r$ related in any way? Are they constants?

Comment: m(dot) is the derivative wrt to {v} and m(prime) is the derivative wrt {r}.   {ψv} partial derivative wrt {v}  and ψr is partial derivative wrt {r}